# Convert a dictionary to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary as

```
 my_dict = {(('KBDL', 'KIAH'), ('KBDL', 'KCVG')): 0, 
 (('KSCK', 'KAFW'), ('KSCK', 'KAFW')): 1}
```

I want to convert it to a dataframe. I use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index')`. However, I get this error: `ValueError: Index data must be 1-dimensional`.

When I change my dictionary to

```
 my_dict= {(('KBDL', 'KIAH'), ('KBDL', 'KCVG'), ('KCVG', 'KLAL')): 0, 
 (('KSCK', 'KAFW'), ('KSCK', 'KAFW')): 1}
```

It works fine.

The desired output I am looking for is a dataframe as

```
(('KBDL', 'KIAH'), ('KBDL', 'KCVG'))    0 
(('KSCK', 'KAFW'), ('KSCK', 'KAFW'))    1
```

Comment: It's running completely fine in both cases.

Comment: Interesting. It might be my old panda version then.

Comment: Your desired output looks more like a Series than a DataFrame, do you mean to do `pd.Series(my_dict)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way running completely fine.

You can try this way too.

```
my_dict = {(('KBDL', 'KIAH'), ('KBDL', 'KCVG')): 0, 
 (('KSCK', 'KAFW'), ('KSCK', 'KAFW')): 1}

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict.items())

print(df)
```

Output

```
                              0  1
0  ((KBDL, KIAH), (KBDL, KCVG))  0
1  ((KSCK, KAFW), (KSCK, KAFW))  1
```